# Multiple WIM files with Windows Setup

Tags: windows, wim

I am wanting to create a USB drive that run Windows Setup. But here at work, we use a different WIM file for every department and update each one very often. I am wanting to be able to run windows setup and be able to choose between all the WIM files instead of just one install.wim.

I know you can compress all WIM files into one, but as often as we update them it would be hard to work with and with thay big of a file you risk curroption very easy.

Is it possible to have multiple WIM files? If so how? I cannot find any sources online..

Comment: Yes?  You can even use a separate WIM file for each partition.  Just setup the partitions, transfer the WIM files from the disk to the HDD, then apply each one in the same order.

Comment: @Ramhound But how? If I add install2.wim, then it does not give me the choice to install from install.wim or install2.wim...

Comment: You develop a script to do it.  The script copies the each .WIM file then applies the .WIM files to each partition.

Comment: I am not sure we are talking about the same things.. I dont want to break it up in partitions, I just want to be able to select "Accounting", "Customer Service". etc just like you would in WDS.

Comment: The concept is the same.  Have the script require user interaction to select the .WIM file that will be copied then applied.